# How can I get mongo db actual size?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

When I run below command in mongo shell,

```
db.stats()
```

I get below and this is wired. When I check mongoDB installation folder it only used around 2 GB disk space?

see below fsTotalSize over 80 GB

[image]

Answer (score 10):

From dbStats [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/):

- `fsTotalSize` and `fsUsedSize` are about the *filesystem* that the database is stored on. They'd be used to get an idea about how much the database could grow to.
- `dataSize` is the size of the all the documents themselves.
- `storageSize` is the size of the data stored on the filesystem (it can be smaller than the `dataSize` if using compression).

So the database takes up `6.7MB` on the filesystem.

Comment: the `indexSize` is also relevant-- it is not included in `dataSize` and it can be pretty large if you have many indexes

Answer (score 0):

[dbStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/)

> dbStats.fsTotalSize - Total size of all disk capacity on the filesystem where MongoDB stores data.

It looks like 80 GB is the total of all disk capacity on the filesystem